# Add styling to specific part of text using i18n

Tags: html, css, json, angular, internationalization

I have a text that is translated to 12 languages. But I would like a specific part of the text to be underlined somehow - preferably inside the json-file where all my translations are.

To take an example the text in English goes like this:

"You've entered the wrong password 3 times. Click here to login again"

I wish to only underline the 'Click here'-part, but have tried (from what I can see was the answer in another SO-question)

```
"wrong": {
    "password": "You've entered the wrong password 3 times. <u>Click here to login again</u>"
```

but that doesn't work. It just shows the text with the actual

> < u >Click here < /u >

showing..

The HTML goes as following:

```
// left out code
<ng-content></ng-content>
<span ng-if="wrongpassword" class="wrongpassword" (click)="wrongpasswordClicked()"> {{ wrongpassword$ | async }} </span>
```

I suspect it shouldn't have anything to do with css, but I've tagged it anyways, since I might be missing something?

update: what I've tried based on ErBu's answer:

```
<div>
  <ng-content {{ wrongpassword$ | async as trythis }} ></ng-content>
  <span *ngIf="wrongpassword" class="wrongpassword" (click)="wrongpasswordClicked()" 
[innerHTML]="trythis">
  </span>
</div>
```

but that doesn't show the text at all... maybe some async operation is missing?

Comment: all text will be treated as regular text (for security reasons) unless explicitly specified otherwise. 
To allow injection of html you can use <div [innerHTML]="your text"></div>

For more details check out angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example

Comment: @ErnestasButa I've already tried that just after span... so `<span [innerHTML] class="wrongpassword" (click)="... etc </span>`

Comment: Should be <span [innerHTML]="<u>Click here to login again</u>"></span> 
becasue based on your snippet you're not setting [innerHTML] to anything :)

Comment: Ah okay in that matter. But in my current setup, I'm using `wrongpassword$ | async` to fetch the text from the json file. Therefore I've tried using HTML inside my JSON-file as shown in the question. That + adding [innerHTML] after `<span ` didn't work. I can't just enter the text inside the HTML after span, since I have 12 different texts. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: not really :D but a possible solution to this might be using await a bit higher in hierarchy.
ex:
<ng-content {{wrongpassword$ | async  as message}}>
     <span [innerHTML]="message" class="wrongpassword" (click)="... etc </span>
</ng-content>
something along these lines

Comment: @ErBu I've tried looking into the documentation + as you can see updated my answer. Now the text don't show at all. Am I missing some async await operation somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

All text will be treated as regular text (for security reasons) unless explicitly specified otherwise. To allow injection of html you can use

```
<div [innerHTML]="your text"></div>
```

For more details check out angular [documentation](http://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example)

In your particular case it should be:

```
  <div>
      <ng-content *ngIf="{{ wrongpassword$ | async as trythis }}" >
         <span class="wrongpassword (click)="wrongpasswordClicked()" 
    [innerHTML]="trythis">
      </span>
    </ng-content>
    </div>
```

P.s I'm adding this as an answer instead of comment for formatting :)

Comment: Your answer work for me just dealing with the i18n translation specifically, I guess OP's problems is more related with the async particular case.